# super() has not attribute parent method

Tags: python, oop, aws-lambda

EDIT: This error is specific to AWS Lambda

Hello I cannot figure out why I am not able to call a parent's method from a child's method.

I have a parent class defined in `classes/IDKKKK.py`

```
class IDKKKK:
    def foobar(self, foo, bar):
        return { 'foo': foo, 'bar': bar}

    def foobar2(self, fo, ob, ar):
        return {'foobar': fo+ob+ar}
```

And I have a child class defined in `classes/OMGGG.py`

```
from classes.IDKKKK import IDKKKK

class OMGGG(IDKKKK):
    def childFoo(self):
        idc = {}
        return super().foobar(idc, super().foobar2('idk', ' what is ', 'going on'))
```

I create an instance of `OMGGG` and call `childFoo()` and I receive `super() has no attribute 'foobar'` in my `main.py`

```
from classes.OMGGG import OMGGG

omg = OMG()
print(omg.childfoo())
```

I am using python 3.7 so `super()` should work, however I tried

`super(OMGGG, self).foobar(...`

to no avail.

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong. I am thinking I might be importing it incorrectly?

Edit: it appears I forgot to add self. This was an error in translation.

Comment: Here is a working example after adding `self`: https://repl.it/repls/SevereEqualKernelmode I don't know what you're doing differently.

Comment: How to do you call `childFoo` exactly? You wrote it as a static method.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I added the instantiation code

Answer (score 3):

Your `childFoo` method needs to take `self` as a parameter:

```
def childFoo(self):
    ...
```

Comment: This is true but it doesn't answer the question. It should probably be a comment.

Comment: @AlexHall I think it actually answers the question. `super` needs that `self` instance to work.

Comment: So this was already in my original code, I forgot it when translating

Comment: @Rodrick but that solves your issue. So your error can either not be reproduced or your original code had that error and you did not notice

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I think you are right. The specific context is in an AWS Lambda function, so it might be specific to that. To clarify, my code had `childFoo(self)` however I am still receiving the error.

Comment: Here is the working example with the code above, just to prove your point... https://repl.it/repls/RuralLooseMode

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `super()`. Just use `self`.

```
from classes.IDKKKK import IDKKKK

class OMGGG(IDKKKK):
    def childFoo(self):
        idc = {}
        return self.foobar(idc, self.foobar2('idk', ' what is ', 'going on'))
```

Technically `foobar` and `foobar2` are also present in `OMGGG` class since it's inheriting them from `IDKKKK` class.

Also as @user2000783 and [Olivier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5079316/olivier-melan%C3%A7on) suggested, pass `self` as a `childFoo` parameter as well.

Comment: When I attempted `self.foobar(...` I received `[ERROR] AttributeError: 'OMGGG' object has no attribute 'foobar'`